# Getting DOCTYPE using selenium webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, doctype, w3c-validation

I am using Selenium webdriver for UI automation purpose. Below is my sample code

```
IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver();
    string url ="http://stackoverflow.com";
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    string pagesource = driver.PageSource;
```

pagesource variable does not have the doctype. I need to  know the DOCTYPE for [W3C validation](http://validator.w3.org). Is there any way to get DOCTYPE of html source through selenium?

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/e8fc1d5b77ec3a9d) shows there is no way to get the Doctype of html source through selenium, instead you can do a HTTP request from .net and get the DOCTYPE. I don't want to do a seperate HTTP request for getting DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 4):

Using FirefoxDriver instead of InternetExplorerDriver will get you the DOCTYPE. Unfortunately this won't solve your problem - the source you're getting with driver.PageSource is already preprocessed by the browser, so trying to validate that code won't give reliable results.

Unfortunately there are no easy solutions.

If your page is not password protected you can use "validate by uri" method.

Otherwise you need to obtain page source. I know two ways of doing it (I implemented both in my project). One is to use proxy. If you are using C# take a look at [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/). Other way would be to make another request using javascript and XMLHttpRequest. You can [find example here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html) (search the page for XMLHttpRequest).

Answer (score 1):

For W3C validation basically we have 3 issues if we automate through selenium webdriver.

1. Getting proper page source since driver.Pagesource is not reliable.
2. Getting doctype of HTML source.
3. Dealing with controls rendered through ajax calls. Since we cannot access these controls in page source how do we get the exact 'Generated source' of the page?

All the above things can be done by executing javascript through selenium web driver.

in a text file called 'htmlsource.txt' store this below code snippet.

---

```
function outerHTML(node){
    // if IE, Chrome take the internal method otherwise build one as lower versions of firefox
        //does not support element.outerHTML property
  return node.outerHTML || (
      function(n){
          var div = document.createElement('div'), h;
          div.appendChild( n.cloneNode(true) );
          h = div.innerHTML;
          div = null;
          return h;
      })(node);
  }


 var outerhtml = outerHTML(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);
var node = document.doctype;
var doctypestring="";
if(node)
{
     // IE8 and below does not have document.doctype and you will get null if you access it.

 doctypestring = "<!DOCTYPE "
         + node.name
         + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '')
         + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') 
         + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '')
         + '>';
         }
         else

         {

             // for IE8 and below you can access doctype like this

         doctypestring = document.all[0].text;
         }
return doctypestring +outerhtml ;
```

---

And now the C# code to access the complete AJAX rendered HTML source with doctype

---

```
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            string jsToexecute =File.ReadAlltext("htmlsource.txt");
            string completeHTMLGeneratedSourceWithDoctype = (string)js.ExecuteScript(jsToexecute);
```

Comment: Still you are facing the same problem - the html code is obtained from DOM, preprocessed by the browser and therefore not reliable.

Comment: But for controls rendered through Ajax, is there any way out to do W3C validation?
FiddlerCore will not help as controls are rendered as data and a javascript converts all the data into HTML Controls.